# Trying to retrieve users profile picture from mysql database.

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue trying to retrieve the users profile link that is stored in MYSQL database.

I tried running this code to select the userprofile (where the users profile picture link is stored) but it came up with a 500 error.

```
        <?php
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT id, userprofile FROM users ');
    $stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
        ?>
```

[image: link]

The Link is stored in the userprofile column.

HTML (function.php has the Database Info in it) :

```
<?php 
    include('functions.php');


    if (!isAdmin()) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
        header('location: ../login.php');
    }


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Admin Home</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Admin - Home Page</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <!-- notification message -->


        <!-- logged in user information -->
        <div class="profile_info">
            <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['userprofile']; ?>" class="img-rounded" width="250px" height="250px" />

            <div>
                <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) : ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['user']['username']; ?></strong>

                    <small>
                        <i  style="color: #888;">(<?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['user']['user_type']); ?>)</i> 
                        <br>
                        <a href="home.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">logout</a>
                        &nbsp; <a href="create_user.php"> + add user</a>
                    </small>

                <?php endif ?>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Image of the test user logged in (Bigfella)

[image: html]

Any Ideas on why It's not retrieving the Image link from the database? Thanks In Advance!!

Comment: save user profile picture `UserId.jpg`. Then you can run `if(file_exists('UserId.jpg'){ $profpic = 'UserId.jpg';} else {$profpic = 'defaultprofpic.jpg'}` You dont want to brother with sql

Answer (score 0):

You need a `}` to close the while() loop and another `}` to close the if statement.

In general to figure out a PHP 500 error, if you don't have access to either change the error reporting or run in command-line mode (most shared hosting will not provide either option), strip down your code a statement (or binary 1/2 your statements) at a time until you have part of it working and add back a line at a time and hopefully you can find the syntax error. 500 can mean a lot of things, but with PHP I find it generally means a fatal syntax error.

Comment: Like this right?   `$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT id, userprofile FROM users ');
    $stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
}
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
 }
        extract($row);` I'm still coming up with a 500 error unable to handle the request.

Comment: No. The { } surround the statements being executed. Using your original code, this would be adding two more `}` at the end, before the `?>`

Comment: Ok I put the Two } before closing the php ?> and it's still coming up with a 500 error. `$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT id, userprofile FROM users ');
    $stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
 }
}`

Comment: Then you need to break it down further. Since it is fairly short, try it one statement at a time - i.e., first just the prepare(), then add execute, then the if but with an empty body (i.e., no while) and then add the while without the extract. Once you narrow down exactly what moves from "run without error" to "500", you can post that information. Debugging 101.

Answer (score 0):

500 html error means that there is some error on the server when trying to serve a page.

this means that you probably generate erroneous url in

`<img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['userprofile']; ?>" class="img-rounded" width="250px" height="250px" />`

or there is an override on the server side that make every call to a certain url path be served by a script.

try checking your `.htaccess` file if you are using Apache/HTTPD

Answer (score 0):

1.) 500 error is server error. The cause here seems to be incorrect syntax. Try this:

```
<?php
    ...

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        // Since you want only one row (one user) you can drop the while
        $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        extract($row);
    }
?>
```

2.) Why are you loading `id` and `userprofile` values from all users?

Since you are showing the information of only one user at a time it would be better if you use something more selective like this:

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT `id`, `userprofile` FROM users WHERE `email`='.$clean['emailAddress']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the 500 Error Unable to handle the request, instead of having the code right at the begining I had moved it down below the `<!DOCTYPE html>` and it worked perfectly fine no error, So I have no clue what happened but its now working! Thank You all that have put in input on helping me try to fix this!! :)